# EASY task in C, drawing ascii rectangles using functions

Tags: c, windows

I have a working program to draw rectangles using "`*`" characters and I need to transform it so that it uses two functions and calls them, one function draws the top and bottom layer all from "`*`" and second function that draws the layers (rows) between, so it starts with "`*`", makes a few spaces and finishes with "`*`"
The working program **without** multiple functions is down below.
Please if you could at least send me on the right path, I tried everything I found :(

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    int rows, columns, x, y;

while(1)
{
    printf("zadejte pocet radku: ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    if (rows<=1)
        continue;
    printf("zadejte pocet sloupcu: ");
        scanf("%d", &columns);
    if (columns<=1)
        continue;
    break;
}

for (x = 0; x < rows; x++) 
{   printf("\n");
    for (y = 0; y < columns; y++) 
    {
        if (x == 0 || x == rows - 1)            
        {
            if (y == 0)  
            printf("*");
            if (y == columns - 1)
            printf("*");
            else
            printf("*");
        }

        else
        {
            if (y == 0)  
            printf("*");
            if (y == columns - 1)
            printf("*");
            else
            printf(" ");
        }   
    }
    }    
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope that's what you want

```
void draw_rows(int col) {
    for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void draw_col(int rows, int col) {
    for(int x = 0; x < rows - 2; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
            if (y == 0 || y == col - 1)  
                printf("*");
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

When you call in the main function:

```
    draw_rows(columns); // draw top line
    draw_col(rows, columns); // draw the columns
    draw_rows(columns); // draw bottom line
```

The complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void draw_rows(int col) {
    for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void draw_col(int rows, int col) {
    for(int x = 0; x < rows - 2; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
            if (y == 0 || y == col - 1)  
                printf("*");
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)

{
    int rows, columns;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("zadejte pocet radku: ");
        scanf("%d", &rows);
        if (rows<=1)
            continue;
        printf("zadejte pocet sloupcu: ");
            scanf("%d", &columns);
        if (columns<=1)
            continue;
        break;
    }

    draw_rows(columns);
    draw_col(rows, columns);
    draw_rows(columns);


    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
zadejte pocet radku: 5                                                                                                                                      
zadejte pocet sloupcu: 6                                                                                                                                    
******                                                                                                                                                      
*    *                                                                                                                                                      
*    *                                                                                                                                                      
*    *                                                                                                                                                      
******
```

Comment: This is clearly a homework assignment, you're not doing him any favors by just giving him the answer like this...

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso At least, he made the code running. I just separate the code for him. If he cannot do anything it's a problem. But here, he was working for the code